# search button code for html table in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, database, twitter-bootstrap

I have table in asp.net which is bound to database using repeater control. I used table instead of gridview but now I cant figure out how to implement search code. Also how can I use gridview instead of table so that it will be easy to do searching,sorting.

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterComp" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Current Status</th>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%#Eval("id")%></td>
                <td>
                    <a href='<%#Eval("href")%>'>
                        <%#Eval("subtype")%>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td><%#Eval("type")%></td>
                <td><%#Eval("status")%></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ComplaintWebsiteConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    String query = "select C.ID as complaintid, S.NAME as STATUS, 'just a string' as ID,'just a string' as href,T.Comp_Type as type,ST.Comp_SubType as subtype from Citizen_complaints C join Complaint_Type T on T.Type_ID=C.Type join Complaint_SubType ST on ST.SubType_ID = C.subtype join COMPLAINT_STATUS S on S.ID = C.STATUS_ID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            dr["href"] = "DeptComplaintStatus.aspx?id=" + dr["complaintid"].ToString();
            dr["id"] = dr["complaintid"].ToString();
        }
        RepeaterComp.DataSource = ds;
        RepeaterComp.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //...
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some Textbox and Button controls. TextBox to input the value to be searched, and button to make this search. And your code will be as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        BindRepeater();
}

protected void BindRepeater(){
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ComplaintWebsiteConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    String query = "select C.ID as complaintid, S.NAME as STATUS, 'just a string' as ID,'just a string' as href,T.Comp_Type as type,ST.Comp_SubType as subtype from Citizen_complaints C join Complaint_Type T on T.Type_ID=C.Type join Complaint_SubType ST on ST.SubType_ID = C.subtype join COMPLAINT_STATUS S on S.ID = C.STATUS_ID";
    if (Session["search"] != null)
        query += " where your_field like '%" + Session["search"].ToString() + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            dr["href"] = "DeptComplaintStatus.aspx?id=" + dr["complaintid"].ToString();
            dr["id"] = dr["complaintid"].ToString();
        }
        RepeaterComp.DataSource = ds;
        RepeaterComp.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //...
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}

protected void YourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Session["search"] = YourTextbox.Text;
    BindRepeater();
}
```

It is a simple solution of your problem.

Comment: Naturally, this code is not "clean". I would not like to use like this. I would like to move the sql-query into stored procedure (first of all, here sql-injection is possible; secondly, stored procedures provide more security, and also makes your code more readable)

Comment: My table is not visible now and on clicking search button nothing is displayed.

Comment: @Ashwini my code exactly will work. Try to debug your code. I think you have to catch some exceptions. You have to check the sql-query, caz' I don't know your tables' structure

Comment: I saw in your code that you use pseudo names for tables. So if you changed *your_field* to *myText*, for example, you have to change it to *tablename.myText* or *T.myText* (if you make pseudo name to your table as *T*)